# Code coverage respect to TFS Work Item

Tags: .net, tfs, code-coverage, tfs-reports

Is there a way to get a report of the code coverage with respect to the Work Item (TFS-Task)?

Maybe in the TFS Build Report or in the Analysis Services-Cube for TFS (in Excel)?

Something like this:

```
 Build 0815     
                covert    not covert
 Code Coverage  154       32
 - Task1        100       15
 - Task2        54        17
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying this for months now and no answer, please refer to:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f35ca079-94d5-4ea5-9e87-80a36a7616f8/getting-code-coverage-for-javascript-unit-tests-under-tfs-build-server-2012?forum=tfsgeneral
I'm still searching but no answer at all.
Anyway, here's a start where I begin from: http://mitchetter.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/publishing-coverage-in-tfs-2008-and-visual-studio-2010/
but it's no a complete solution and it's not working at all under VS 2012 as well as TFS 2012.